# Gain/Loss on Bonds (Fidelity)

Tags: bonds, fidelity

I have bought a series of corporate bonds on Fidelity and sold a couple of them after a month. I wondered the best way to measure how much money I made, given how complicated bonds can be.

I know Fidelity Gain/Loss accounts for Accrued Interests. However, is there anything Fidelity does not consider that I need to? I would love to provide any additional detail. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The actual PnL for bonds is not complicated at all - *pricing bonds* can be complicated, but the actual gain for bonds is as simple as what you sold them for less what you paid for them.

If you did not receive a coupon in the period, the absolute gain would just be the sales price minus the purchase price.

the *relative* gain would just be

```
(sales price)
-------------  - 1
(purch price)
```

If you did receive one or more coupons, you would just add the coupon(s) to the sales price in both cases.

Note that these prices should be the actual prices that you paid (and received) for the bonds, meaning that they *include* accrued interest.